# How do I plot multiple density curves and add a legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

dear swarm intelligence.

I am facing an issue trying to plot different density curves in one ggplot object and having it also display a legend.
I have tried two approaches so far:

```
multiple_density <- ggplot() + 
  geom_density(data = df1, mapping = aes(x = df1$col1), color = "black") + 
  geom_density(data = df2, mapping = aes(x = df2$col1), color = "red") +
  geom_density(data = df3, mapping = aes(x = df3$col1), color = "green") +
  theme(legend.position = "right") +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("black" = "black", "red" = "red", "green" = "green"), name = "key") +
  theme_classic()
```

And:

```
combined_df <- bind_rows(df1, df2, df3, .id = "id")

multiple_density <- ggplot() +
  geom_density(data = multiple_density, mapping = aes(x = combined_df$col1) + 
  theme(legend.position = "right") + 
  theme_classic()
```

In the first code, I would expect the `scale_colour_manual` bit to do the trick, which is what I have found in answers to such questions before, this does however not work for me.
Could the problem here be, that the different data frames do not have the same number of values in their respective `col1`?

The second code does not give me 3 distinct curves but takes all values from the 3 data frames together as one density curve, which I obviously don't want.

I am probably missing something obvious here, but any help would still be appreciated!

Comment: To get a legend to appear, the defining characteristic, `color` in this case, needs to be *inside* the call to `aes`.  Also, it might be better in the long term to `bind your datasets together, creating an ID variable and then using the ID variable on the right hand side of the `color` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment above, and based on random data:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- tibble(col1=rnorm(500, mean=0))
df2 <- tibble(col1=rnorm(500, mean=2))
df3 <- tibble(col1=rnorm(500, mean=4))

df1 %>% 
  bind_rows(df2, df3, .id="DF") %>% 
  ggplot() +
    geom_density(aes(x=col1, color=DF))
```

[image]